# Subsetting Flex Array

Tags: apache-flex, arrays

I want to subset an array.I have the following array

```
public var sellAmount:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([
     {month:"Jan", sell:2000},
     {month:"Feb", sell:5000},
     {month:"Mar", sell:4000},
     {month:"Apr", sell:6000},
     {month:"May", sell:3000},
     {month:"Jun", sell:9000},         
     {month:"Jul", sell:1100},
     {month:"Aug", sell:4000},
     {month:"Sep", sell:1000},
     {month:"Oct", sell:500},
     {month:"Nov", sell:4000},
     {month:"Dec", sell:3000}
     ])
```

Now based on user requirement I want to select  a range of sell data for some month.For example sometime it may be sells data from Apr to Dec,sometime may be Jul-Oct.How can I do that without hampering the original array

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ArrayCollection.filterFunction](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction), though your use of strings for the month makes it a tad more difficult:

```
function filterSalesData(startMonth:uint, endMonth:uint) {
    sellAmount.filterFunction = monthRangePredicate;
    sellAmount.refresh();

    function monthRangePredicate(obj : Object) {
        var months : Array = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", etc]; // TOOD: promote to class level

        var monthIndex : uint = months.indexOf(obj.month);

        return (monthIndex >= startMonth && monthIndex <= endMonth);
    }
}

filterSalesData(6, 9); // july to october
filterSalesData(3, 11); // april to december
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot.But I did it in slightly different way.Instead of using data as ArrayCollection, I used it as array and then I used slice function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filterFunction for the ArrayCollection which applies the filter as required.